# What is the force system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, charge, free-body-diagram, spring

[image]

Spring Force = $F_s$

Charge Force = $F$

If the system is balanced
Based on Newton's Law
On the horizontal line
Is it
$2F_s = F$
Or $F_s = F$ ?

Comment: What about gravity?

Comment: Lets talk about in horizontal line

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try drawing a free-body diagram. The horizontal force on the mass is spring force and charge(if the mass has charged). The direction of restoring force is in such a direction to restore the initial state of spring and the direction of coulomb force depends on the sign of charge.

Comment: The charge pushes each other, so there 2 springs, so wouldnt it be 2Fs + F = 0?

Comment: The spring force is the contact force and so it can only apply a force to a mass which is attached to it.

Comment: So the on side of mass theres 1 spring force and 1 F ?

Comment: Finding F, is F=1/(4pi.miu.) . Q^2/r^2 right? So, the F is on left mass is F=1/(4pi.miu.) . Q^2/r^2, and on right side also?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what are you saying. But the restoring force should be equal to coulomb force in equilibrium conditon.